# Using Sinatra and ruby to interface to HTML buttons

Tags: jquery, html, ruby, ajax, sinatra

**Disclosure:** I know nothing about web programming

**Background to problem:**
I have an environmental testing chamber testing embedded computers at various temperatures. It is controlled by a windows application. I can control the chamber via ruby and the Win32API interface of the control application. The chamber is far from my office and I would remotely monitor the state and trigger a change via a Web interface. Sinatra makes it easy to show the state via a web server.

**My problem:** I want to click on a button on the status webpage and send a command via Sinatra and Ruby to the application without switching to a different page. I cant find any examples or information for something like that.

**The Answer:** You can use Ajax(as in the accepted answer) but I am going with post and reload the page. It is a lot simpler but not as smooth.

Comment: You want to use ajax... but maybe before doing so learn a bit about web development, it's not that easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you already have a form that POSTs to a sinatra handler and does what you want?

If so, you could easily make it ajaxy by using jQuery.

1. Add jquery.js to your public directory & require it from the layout
2. Add some js to post to your handler when your button is clicked.

   ```
   // assuming your form has id=myform
   // defines a callback on submission of the form #myform.
   $("#myform").submit(function() {
     //posts the contents of the form to /action using ajax
     $.post("/action", $("#myform").serialize(), function(result){
       // assuming result is a string of the updated data in html
       // and assuming that your data goes in an element with the id data-table
       $("#data-table").html(result)
     });
     return false; // prevents the form from submitting normally
   });
   ```

jquery docs for

- [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)
- [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)
- [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)
- [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to […] send a command via (the server) […] without switching to a different page

This is known as *Ajax* and is usually implemented using [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.jibbering.com/2002/4/httprequest.html).